# How to pass dropdownlist Id as parameter to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

On the client side I need to call javascript function "changeSchool" with selector's Id as parameter, as soon user selects new option (school in this case). How to pass selector's Id to such javascript function?

Table in the view contains following drop down lists:

```
 @{
for (var i = 0; i < Model.StudentApplications.Count(); i++)
                {       
                <tr>
                    ...
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentApplications[i].SchoolId, Model.StudentApplications[i].SchoolList, new { onchange = "changeSchool(?);" })</td>
                    ... 
                </tr>

                }
              }
```

EDIT:

From the source code I can see that ids is generated: id="StudentApplications_0__SchoolId", 
id="StudentApplications_1__SchoolId", ...
etc.

Comment: show your effort in javascript here.

Comment: Why did you remove the answer status from my post?

Comment: Your answer is working, but I need dropdownlist ID as javascript function parameter, see my edit.

Comment: My post provided you with the answer, you just needed to strip out the useful info. In my mind I provided you with a solution. So my post deserves to be marked as the answer, true?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps?

```
onchange = "changeSchool(" + Model.StudentApplications[i].SchoolId + ");"
```

Comment: The name 'm' do not exist in the current context

Comment: replace "m" with Model?